# Relation between eigenspace and Galois group ( Elliptic curve point counting)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, galois-theory, finite-fields, arithmetic-geometry

Let E be an elliptic curve over $F_p$. Suppose that its *j* invarient is not supersingular and that $j\neq 0 $ or 1728.

Then the modular polynomial $\Phi_l(j,T)$ has a zero  $\tilde{\jmath} \in \mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ if and only if the kernel $C$ of the corresponding isogeny $E \mapsto E/C$ is a one-dimensional eigenspace of $\phi^r_p$ in $E[l]$, with $\phi_p$ the Frobenius endomorphism of $E$.

In the proof: If $C$ is an eigenspace of $\phi_p^r$, it is stable under the action of the Galois group generated by $\phi_p^r$. Therefore the isogeny $E \mapsto E/C$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ and the $j$ invariant $\tilde{\jmath}$ of $E/C$ is contained in $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ .
[Counting points on eliptic curve over finite field](http://www.numdam.org/article/JTNB_1995__7_1_219_0.pdf)  page no:236.

Can someone help me to understand the prrof, I dont know the relation between eigenspace of $\phi_p^r$ and Galois group generated by $\phi_p^r$. Please help me with a small example or, theorem providing this.

Comment: Does it mean $C = ker(L)$ where $L = \phi_{p^r}-m \in End(E)$ for some integer $m$ so that $L(E) \simeq E/C$ ?

Comment: I am not sure, I think just powering, $\phi_p$

Comment: What do you mean ? There is a better version of [your pdf](http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~ritzenth/cours/point-counting-ec.pdf). It seems they assume $m= 1$ so that $C \subset E(\mathbb{F}_{p^r})$. In that case it is clear $E \mapsto E/C$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$

Comment: can you please tell me where $\phi_{p^r}$ is defined in your book?

Comment: The Frobenius automorphism is $\phi_p \in Gal(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/ \mathbb{F}_p), \phi_p(x) = x^p$. Iterating it $r$ times we get $\phi_p^r (x) = x^{p^r} = \phi_{p^r}(x)$. Here we are assuming $C$ is the kernel of the endomorphism $L : E(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}) \to E(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$, $L(x,y) = (x^{p^r},y^{p^r})- [m] (x,y)$ with $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $m=1$ I'm not sure. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044840/frobenius-morphism-on-elliptic-curves) for the basic properties of $\phi_p^n$ on $E$

Comment: [link] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325581/elliptic-curve-isogenies-frobenius-endomorphism-relation-to-characteristic-equa) I have asked the relation between characteristic polynomial of $\phi_p^r$ and kernel. So, we ant take $L$ in a way it gives eigenspace. isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. [this pdf p. 13](http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~ritzenth/cours/point-counting-ec.pdf) is more readable. You asked the same question, and you didn't state the definition of the modular polynomial.

Comment: I am sorry, I just asked you to have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325581/elliptic-curve-isogenies-frobenius-endomorphism-relation-to-characteristic-equa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60626/discussion-between-student-and-user1952009).

Comment: The "conversely" follows directly from the definition of the modular polynomial as stated the previous page.