# Explanation of Frobenius endomorphism on elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-homomorphism, frobenius-groups

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the Frobenius endomorphism for an elliptic curve.

Specifically, If $E$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$, then the Frobenius endomorphism $\pi$ is defined as

> $\pi : E \rightarrow E,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$    $(x,y) \rightarrow (x^q,y^q)$

This definition doesn't make sense to me b/c the Frobenius endomorphism is defined as carrying an element, $a$ to $a^p$ where $p$ is the characteristic of the ring (and is prime). So it seems like the definition should be $(x, y) \rightarrow (x, y)^q$ = $(x, y) + (x, y) + ... (x, y)$, $q$ times since elliptic curve addition is between 2 points. Why are the $x$ and $y$ values calculated separately?

Here is a concrete example I don't understand.

- Take the curve $E/\mathbb{F}_q : y^2 = x^3 + 4x + 3$ where $q = 67$
- Let $P = (15, 50)$. We know $[q](P) = P + P + ... + P$ (q times) = $[67]P = (24, 56)$
- The Frobenius endomorphism, $\pi$ maps $P$ to itself. However, $(15, 50) \rightarrow (15, 50)$ is different from $(15, 50) \rightarrow (24, 56)$.
- Basically, I believe my assumption is that the Frobenius endomorphism applies the elliptic curve addition law to a point, $P$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$, $q$ times, however, it seems like this assumption is wrong.

Comment: I think that $x$ and $y$ may be the coordinates of the point, which are elements of the field, where the Frobenius map is a ring morphism.

Comment: $E$ is *defined* over $\Bbb{F}_q$ means that the coefficients of the equation defining $E$ are in the field $\Bbb{F}_q$. The coordinates of an arbitrary point $(x,y)$ on $E$ belong to an algebraic closure $\overline{\Bbb{F}_q}$ (or some other extension field. And, yes the Frobenius is applied to the coordinates, it does not rely on the group operation of the elliptic curve but rather on the arithmetic of th underlying field. Because the curve is defined over $\Bbb{F}_q$, and $z^q=z$ for all $z\in\Bbb{F}_q$, it follows that $(x^q,y^q)$ also satisfies the equation of $E$.

Comment: (cont'd) It follows that $\pi$ permutes the points of $E$, and this is what we are trying to study. Because Frobenius is an automorphism of the field, $\pi$ respects the elliptic curve addition, and is thus an endomorphism.

Comment: To re-phrase what you are saying to make sure I understand. The Frobenius endomorphism will map all points on $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ to themself since $z^q = z$ for all $z \in \mathbb{F}_q$. B/c it maps all points on $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ to themself, it is an automorphism, and thus a homomorphism.

Comment: @Compacto - When you say ring morphism, what is the ring in question? $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is a group, but I don't think there is a multiplication operation, so it can't be a ring, right?

Comment: $[2](x,y)$ means $(x,y)+(x,y)$ (addition in the group law of the elliptic curve) not the same as $(x,y)^q $ which means $(x^q,y^q)$. If $(x,y)$ satisfies $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ then so does $(x^q,y^q)$ whenever $a,b\in \Bbb{F}_q$ and $x,y$ lie in a field containing $\Bbb{}_q$. The Frobenius is an automorphism on the group $E(\overline{\Bbb{F}_q})$ (which is the identity on $E(\Bbb{F}_q)$) but not on the function field and coordinate ring of the elliptic curve where it is only an "endomorphism".

Comment: Let $F(X,Y)$ be a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb F_q$. Then $F(X,Y)^q = F(X^q,Y^q)$, so if $F(x,y) = 0$ then $F(x^q,y^q) = 0$. If $x,y\in\mathbb F_q$ then $x^q = x, y^q = y$, but when they are not their image under Frobenius (which is indeed induced by a ring, even field, morphism on the coordinate field) gives a different point.

Comment: This makes it into a morphism of curves. In the case of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_q$, we demand the 0 to be defined over $\mathbb F_q$, making it a fixed point, which actually is sufficient for it to be a morphism of elliptic curves.

Comment: As Jyrki said, the ring is the base field for the curve (fields of characteristic $p$. The basic Frobenius is first considered on these fields as a ring morphism (remember here $(a+b)^p= a^p+b^p$. Raising to the power of $q= p^n$ is just this basic map applied $n$ times), and since points of the curve are pairs of elements of these fields (coordinates), you can apply Frobenius to those two coordinates, obtaining a morphism on the curve (with respect to addition of points, which I think is equal to addition of coordinates).

Comment: This other post may be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044840/frobenius-morphism-on-elliptic-curves

Comment: @reuns. Got it. I assumed the Frobenius endomorphism took points on $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and applied the elliptic curve addition law to them $q$ times. $[q]P \neq P$ (added example in my post). But it looks like Frobenius operates on pairs of numbers in the underlying field, $F_q$.

Comment: Good. For example when $x=32$ you get $x^3+4x+3=2$. $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $67$, so the point $(32,\sqrt2)$ has its coordinates in the (unique) quadratic extension field $K=\Bbb{F}_{67^2}=\Bbb{F}_{67}[\sqrt2]$. Here the Frobenius is the non-trivial automorphism of $K$ so it maps $(x,y)=(32,\sqrt2)\mapsto (32,-\sqrt2)$. You are welcome to check that $(\sqrt2)^{67}\equiv-\sqrt2\pmod{67}$. All because $2^{33}\equiv-1$ by virture of two being a quadratic non-residue.